# Include app contents in Windows 8.1 search result

Tags: c#, search, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Is it in any way possible to include search results from my app in the Windows 8.1 search results? E.g. in the list on the Search charm or in the Smart Search page?

I found the `ContentIndexer` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.contentindexer) to add content to the system index, but it doesn't seem to add anything to the "system" search results.